# Why does it say "Skywalker" in this shot of Bradley Cooper recording the voice of Rocket Racoon?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1

This short video shows some clips of actor Bradley Cooper performing and recording the voice of Rocket Racoon: "[Bradley Cooper as Rocket Raccoon - Marvel's Guardians of the Galaxy Blu-ray Featurette Clip 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IvdHeqxbDrc)" (from the YouTube channel *Marvel Entertainment*).

In one shot you can briefly see in the background the words:

> SKYWALKER
>
> Groot woozily comes to his feet
>
> PROPERTY OF MARVEL

which are displayed on a monitor that looks like it is showing a (poor quality) clip of the movie, presumably this is what the actors use to sync their lines with the action.

[image: Bradley recording his lines with the monitor behind described above]

What is the significance of the word "SKYWALKER"?

Comment: Possibly being done in a [Skywalker Sound](https://www.skysound.com/) studio?

Comment: "Skywalker Sound" is a large, well known basically recording studio for movies, TV and commercials.  (Obviously, Skywalker Sound was created by George Lucas.)  It's by far the most famous in the business, you can read about it here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skywalker_Sound

Comment: In Episode X, it's revealed that Rocket is really a poorly made clone of Anakin

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Presumably this is referring to Skywalker Sound, the company behind the sound on *Guardians of the Galaxy*. [See their project page for reference](https://www.skysound.com/projects/guardians-of-the-galaxy/).

[image: Screenshot of the project page showing the GotG poster and some of the Skywalker staff on the right]

Note that "SKYWALKER" will just be their watermark which is the same as the "PROPERTY OF MARVEL" watermark used for the same reasons.

Comment: FWIW I originally thought the person in the background of the first clip in the video was Christopher Boyes (first in the list on the prject page) but I'm not too sure about that now.

Answer (score 14):

Other answers give the 'who' the Skywalker refers to, Skywalker Sound Studios.  The 'why' is that Marvel Studios does not want their movies to make it onto file sharing sites before being released.

I'm sure they have tight controls on who they share scenes from the movie with before being released.  Adding the 'Property of Marvel' watermark
makes it much less likely.  Even if it did make it to file sharing sites, the watermark would be very hard to remove and would be annoying to watchers.   If you wanted to see a 'clean' movie you would have to rent/buy one.

Adding the 'Skywalker' watermark in big letters across the middle of the screen makes it even harder to remove and more obtrusive, which isn't a big deal when the scenes are just being used as reference for the voice actors.  If the movie or even still frames from the movie do make it to file or image sharing sites without blacking out the entire center of the screen, then Marvel knows where to look for the leak.

Comment: "Marvel knows where to look for the leak" Exactly. It's a multi-purpose watermark.